# Save session in J2EE

Tags: java, database, jsp, session

I don't know if the way how I'm saving the session is correct. Nowadays I use:

```
private Map<String, Object> session;
```

But, when I modify the changes, it's save on data base, but if I consult again the profile user it's show me the profile previous to the modification. I show the flow with pictures:

1- The login: is a jsp with a form with how call to action Login]
    in the action do a query to the data base to check the user when I get the user I pass the object to a map:

[login](https://www.dropbox.com/s/chju5nfupaki992/login.JPG?dl=0)

2- Show user profile: On the welcome page there are a menu [User profile, schedule, ....I do click in User profile option [jsp with a href how call to action perfilUsuario.action] and show the user profile in a jsp:

[show user profile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ph7k3dcxfwwufat/profile.jpg?dl=0/)

3- Modify user profile: On the user profile option there is modify I click [call to modify action]:

[modify user profile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7glt2d4lqn5otu/modify.JPG?dl=0/)

4- DataBase check: I check the data base and it's ok:

[database check](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ksfv8mj7lct90xr/dataBase.JPG?dl=0/)

5- I check again the user and there is nothing changed:

[user profile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ph7k3dcxfwwufat/profile.jpg?dl=0/)

But when I logout and login the change in the profile is done. 
Me ask is if I'm doing something wrong in the action "modificar"

Modificar.java
    package modificar.action;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;
import registrar.model.Usuario;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import utils.Traspasar;

public class Modificar extends ActionSupport  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Usuario usuario;
private Map<String, Object> session;

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}


public Map<String, Object> getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
    this.session = session;
}

@Override
public String execute()  {

    session = new HashMap<String, Object>();


    // iria la parte de datos con hibernate
    System.out.println("Se hace el traspaso de datos a mySQL");

    Traspasar.datos2(usuario.getNombre(), usuario.getApellido(),
            usuario.getNIFCIF(), usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getTelefono(),
            usuario.getEmpresa(), usuario.getDepartamento(),
            usuario.getUsuario(), usuario.getContrasena());


    session.put("loginId", usuario.getUsuario());
    session.put("contrasena",usuario.getContrasena());
    session.put("nombre", usuario.getNombre());
    session.put("apellido", usuario.getApellido());
    session.put("NIFCIF", usuario.getNIFCIF());
    session.put("email", usuario.getEmail());
    session.put("telefono", usuario.getTelefono());
    session.put("empresa", usuario.getEmpresa());
    session.put("departamento", usuario.getDepartamento());

    return SUCCESS;

    }
}
```

Comment: Normally that not how to handle session in JEE, unless you are implemeting something of your own

Comment: Well I saw that finally the problem that I have is not about the session, it's about other subject so I think that this threat could be closed by an administrator. Thanks for all.